# how to create file in all subdirectories using batch loop

Tags: batch-file

Any way to create a **text file** in all **subdirectories** using batch here is folder structure. I want to make a readme.txt file **with content: downloaded-from-xyz.com** in all directories and subdirectories

this command is working but not putting file in all sub directories

```
for /D %x in (movies) do copy readme.txt %x
```

```
for /D %%x in (movies) do copy readme.txt %%x
```

folder tree:

```
C:/movies
C:/movies/hd
C:/Movies/english
C:/movies/thumbnail/hd
```

Comment: If you want it to put it inside every folder under the folder movies then you need to use the correct  logic for the `SET` of the `FOR` command.  As it is right now you are just telling it to use the folder movies.  So change your `SET` to `(movies\*)` if you want it to go one folder deep.  If you want it to go multiple levels of folders then you need to use the `/R` option with the `/D` option.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
cd movies
FOR /R /D %%t in (.) do (
    cd %%t

    echo downloaded-from-xyz.com > readme.txt
    
    cd ..
)
```